# What all authentication are supported by OData?

Tags: rest, authentication, odata, restful-authentication

As per my knowledge, OData currently supports Basic Authentication.Is there any other authentication supported by it?

Any plan for Kerberos authentication support in future?

Comment: Authentication is provided by the service (ie your code). It's not part of the OData protocol. You can use whatever is supported by your web server and framework. If you are using IIS and .NET, Windows authentication supported OOTB from day 1

Comment: How do we know the service is using which type of authenication